# How To fix 'Property "string" does not exist on type "object"' error in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement [Scroll Restoration](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/scroll-restoration.md) in React Router using Typescript with code below.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export interface IProps {
  prevProps?: any;
  location: object;
  pathname?: any;
}

class ScrollToTop extends Component<IProps, object> {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps?: any) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {

    return this.props.children;

  }

}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

However, I continue to receive the following TS error when I add types for location and pathname.

`(14,29): Property 'pathname' does not exist on type 'object'.`

Why is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, `withRouter` has to be imported from `react-router`.

But to answer your question on Typescript error, this is because `location` has been defined as a `object` for typescript without specifying properties on it. This is why there is an error when you try to access `pathname` on it.

Luckily, you do not have to write out all properties on location prop. Instead you can install react-router types with:

```
npm install --save @types/react-router @types/react-router-dom
```

When creating a component that inherits these props (match, location, history), simply extend `RouteComponentProps`:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";

interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  // other props
}
```

Comment: `withRouter` is available from `react-router-dom`. Nonetheless, your answer worked. I previously installed @types/react-router and @types/react-router-dom, but I guess I didn't use the `--save` flag. I simply reinstalled with the line above.